# npm ERR! not found: git

Tags: ember-app-kit

When I want to copy the **ember-app-kit-master** file in my project, I execute

```
cmd: cd C:\Users\hp-pc\Desktop\MyApp
```

then

```
cmd: npm install
```

But I got some errors:

```
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "G:\\Publish\\nodeJs\\\\node.exe" "G:\\Publish\\nodeJs\\node_mo
dules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\hp-pc\Desktop\MyApp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.9
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
```

This is part of my package.json :

```
 "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     "load-grunt-config": "git://github.com/Pradeek/load-grunt-config.git",
  }
```

When I remove settings about git, it works fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install Git-scm on your computer. NPM uses git to get the repos. Also, the command `npm docs` can be used with github to fetch the docs. So perhaps npm checks if got is installed. http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: can you give me a link? i have already installed github and git shell.

Comment: thanks very much,it works fine, i installed with the option of bash :)